# simple modal loader

Tags: loader, simplemodal

I am new in using jquery. I am trying add in the simplemodal.js (Eirc Martin's simple modal) a function called 'jBox' that will take the data (ie link) and options and using ajax will load the content into the modal container. This way I want on my pages in several places easy call this function

```
    jBox = function(address, options){
        $.get(address, function(data) {     
            $.modal(data);
        }); 
    };
});
```

The code is working fine, but i would like to add a loading image before the content is fully loaded. There is a lots of similar posts about loader/ spinner in simplebox but none of the works for me.
I was trying following code

```
$('#test').load('<img src="loader.gif">').html(data);
$('#test').modal();
```

But, some way, it doesnt work for me. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: the first code snippet has extra close brackets

Comment: Thank you Shivan. My mistake while copying the code. The first code works fine. Just dont know how to add a  loader to it. The code below it from some reason pasted into the function dosnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events.

```
$("body").on({
    ajaxStart: function() { 
        $(this).addClass("loading"); // so page knows it's in loading state
        // .. your modal code
    },
    ajaxStop: function() { 
        $(this).removeClass("loading"); // not it loading state anymore
        // .. What you should do if loading is done. (eg. hide modal)
    }    
});
```

In this case I set the body class to 'loading'. So you can do some magic in css if you like.
I tend to use it to disable forms as well.

```
body.loading div.some-class {
    // your special style for during loading
}
```